# python 3.4 3 unindent does not match any outer indentation level error

Tags: python, syntax-error, indentation

```
import random

secret = random.randint(1, 99)
guess = 0
tries = 0

print ("AHOY! I´m the dread pirate Roberts, and I have a secret!")
print ("It is a number from 1 to 99. I´ll give you 6 tries.")

while guess != secret and tries < 6:
    guess = input ("what´s yer guess?")
    if guess < secret:
        print ("Too low, ye scurvy dog!")
    elif guess > secret:
        print ("Too high, lamdlubber!")
    tries = tries + 1

    if guess == secret:
         print ("Avast! Ye got it! Found my secret, ye did!")
         else:
         print ("No more guesses! Better luck next time matey!")
         print ("The secret number was", secret)
```

What am I doing wrong? Im using the book helloworld book to learn how to programme, its the first "task" and it keeps telling me python 3.4 3 unindent does not match any outer indentation level. Pls help

Comment: Your `else` statement doesn't look like its matching the `if` indentation.

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: If you are asking questions about errors such as this its best to post the full exception.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to un-indent the else at line 20.

Correction:

```
import random

secret = random.randint(1, 99)
guess = 0
tries = 0

print ("AHOY! I´m the dread pirate Roberts, and I have a secret!")
print ("It is a number from 1 to 99. I´ll give you 6 tries.")

while guess != secret and tries < 6:
    guess = input ("what´s yer guess?")
    if guess < secret:
        print ("Too low, ye scurvy dog!")
    elif guess > secret:
        print ("Too high, lamdlubber!")
    tries = tries + 1

    if guess == secret:
         print ("Avast! Ye got it! Found my secret, ye did!")
    else: # THIS was indented
         print ("No more guesses! Better luck next time matey!")
         print ("The secret number was", secret)
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction , it did work now, though, i am a total noob and cant see whats the difference in the codes xD

Comment: The `if..else` needs to be unindented one more level. This will also fail due to the comparison between `int` and `str`.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

1. I suppose it worked on your build, but I corrected the backtick to a regular quote `'`.
2. You weren't changing the guess to an integer, so the comparison failed.
3. The `if guess == secret` check and its corresponding `else` were indented too much. They needed to be completely out of the `while` loop.
4. The content of the `if guess == secret` block was indented five spaces instead of four. Not a problem this time, but these inconsistencies can create problems sometimes.

```
import random

secret = random.randint(1, 99)
guess = 0
tries = 0

print ("AHOY! I'm the dread pirate Roberts, and I have a secret!")
print ("It is a number from 1 to 99. I'll give you 6 tries.")

while guess != secret and tries < 6:
    guess = int(input ("what's yer guess?"))
    if guess < secret:
        print ("Too low, ye scurvy dog!")
    elif guess > secret:
        print ("Too high, landlubber!")
    tries = tries + 1

if guess == secret:
    print ("Avast! Ye got it! Found my secret, ye did!")
else:
    print ("No more guesses! Better luck next time matey!")
    print ("The secret number was", secret)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. What did the error say, @SusanaTimóteo?